# Getting the most appropriate encoding from a url HTTP post response

Tags: python, character-encoding, nlp, python-requests, text-extraction

What is the most appropriate method to determine the encoding in the text from a webpage. I process webpages from various languages and use Python and the "[requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/)" library. The aim is eventually to be able to get clean text using some text extraction library for text mining projects

```
resp = requests.get(url)
```

Now I know that we have the following options:

1)

```
    from requests.utils import get_encoding_from_headers
    encoding = get_encoding_from_headers(resp.headers)
    html = (resp.content).decode(encoding)
```

2)

```
    from requests_toolbelt.utils.deprecated import get_encodings_from_content
    encoding = get_encodings_from_content(resp.content)
    html = (resp.content).decode(encoding)
```

3)

```
    from requests_toolbelt.utils.deprecated import get_encodings_from_content
    html = get_unicode_from_response(resp)
```

I processed around a 1000 urls and was expecting 1) and 2) to be the same but 20% of the time that wasnt the case. In those 20% cases (1) would give "ISO-8859-1" which from looking at the code means it didnt find the charset in the header and (2) mostly gave out "utf8"

Now does someone have some experience with this as to what the most appropriate technique among these is or if a better more cleaner way exists?

Comment: thanks for the correction @DhiaTN

Answer (score 0):

Don't trust the declared encoding, just test it directly on the HTML code you got with the [chardet](https://github.com/chardet/chardet) or [cchardet](https://github.com/PyYoshi/cChardet) (faster) libraries:

```
import requests
try:
    # this module is much faster
    import cchardet as chardet
except ImportError:
    import chardet

response = requests.get(url)

guessed_encoding = chardet.detect(response.content)['encoding']

if guessed_encoding is not None:
    try:
        htmltext = response.content.decode(guessed_encoding)
    except UnicodeDecodeError:
        htmltext = response.text
else:
    htmltext = response.text

# do something with htmltext...
```